# Adding an underline to the word "Abstract" in \abstract?

Tags: formatting, abstract, apa6

To meet the requirements of the university, I need to be able to underline the word Abstract in my dissertation? Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how best to do this using the `apa6` class? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\maketitle` command responsible for typesetting the abstract:

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{The Title}
\threeauthors{John and Jim}{Mary and Sue}{Nick}
\threeaffiliations{U of A}{U of B}{U of C}
\abstract{text}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\abstractname}{\underline{\abstractname}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding to my query. This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @MorganHill: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer that you think best solved your problem In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\underline{Abstract}}
```

This may not work well with other language settings (that is, an automated adaptation), but it doesn't require any packages.

Comment: I tried using this option, and I was unable to make it work.

Comment: @MorganHill: My suggestion is virtually identical to @_GozaloMedina's, so if his worked, mine should to. I tested it with his MWE. Not sure what you're doing wrong.